# Why is a dialog box being displayed behind the main form?

Tags: delphi, forms

Earlier today I went to open a file in a Delphi app I wrote. For some reason the connection to the file's network was down--reasons unimportant--and Windows created a dialog box alerting me to the problem. My app's main form, however, was on top of the newly created dialog (i.e., there was a form for my app, for the File Open dialog, and for the warning dialog box). The warning dialog was modal, and hidden behind the main form. Obviously, I had a problem.

Any idea what's going on, or how I can remedy the issue? The main form's position property is set to poDesigned, and I save/load the form's position on close/startup, I'm too much of a newbie to even know what info would help you diagnose the problem. To be clear, though, the issue was *not* the File Open dialog--that was displayed where it was supposed to be displayed--the issue was the warning dialog.

Thanks, as always --

Comment: What was the error message in the dialog, and what version of Windows?

Comment: It's Delphi 2006 and Win 7. The error message was something about Windows not being able to connect to a network. ... My thanks to you both, and everyone else, for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why is Windows creating a dialog in your app. Which API call resulted in that happening? Normal file operations don't show UI.

Most likely you were using an API function that can show UI, perhaps from the shell API. Any function that can show a modal dialog will request an owner `HWND`.

For example consider [`MessageBox()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx), a function that you know will show a modal dialog in your app. Its first parameter is called `hWnd` and is documented

> A handle to the owner window of the
>   message box to be created. If this
>   parameter is NULL, the message box has
>   no owner window.

Raymond Chen has a [whole series of articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/tags/modality/) on modality which explain why setting this is important.

I have a hunch that you are calling some Win32 API function that shows modal UI, and are not setting the owner `HWND` correctly. Of course, I could be completely wrong, but there's not more information to go on.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop this by using [SetErrorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680621%28VS.85%29.aspx) before trying to open the file on the network share:

```
var
  OldErrorMode: Integer;
begin
  OldErrorMode := SetErrorMode(SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
  try
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      // ....
    end;
  finally
    SetErrorMode(OldErrorMode);
  end;
end;
```

Later versions of Delphi (IIRC, D2007 and higher) added an overloaded version of  TOpenDialog.Execute that accepts a window handle as a parameter; this sets the TOpenDialog's parent and prevents the OpenDialog (and any error window it generates) from appearing behind the main window.

NOTE: You can get to the background dialog (from Windows) using Alt+Tab to cycle through until your application comes back up; this usually brings the hidden dialog forwaard on top of your form.

Comment: Doesn't the VCL set that error mode for you? I've never explicitly called `SetErrorMode` so I can only assume somebody is doing it on my behalf!

Comment: @David: Nope, not AFAIK. That's how I know about SetErrorMode in the first place. :) And, as I said, later versions of Delphi provide the HWND parameter in the overloaded Execute to help with this issue. Maybe you haven't used a TOpenDialog that had an error when trying to display a folder?

Comment: @Ken I've always set my owner `HWND` correctly. That's really the fundamental issue. In fact I think you may be misleading OP and encouraging a certain amount of sweeping real problems under the carpet by concentrating on SetErrorMode, if this is indeed the reason for the observed behaviour.

Comment: @David: No, not sweeping the problem under the rug, if I understand the problem (which I think I do, having experienced it in earlier versions of Delphi with an unstable network at a former job). Also, I just checked, and there's no mention of SetErrorMode in the source of Dialogs.pas that shipped with XE. (And how did you set the owner HWND for TOpenDialog when there wasn't a way to do that until D2007?) And last, if you check MSDN for the specific flag I mentioned, you'll see that the error is returned to the calling app; this is in no way sweeping the problem under the rug.

Comment: @Ken I've never used the built in file dialogs, I've always used modified versions to fix the owner HWND. Latterly I used modified versions to support Vista dialogs. I don't mean sweeping the file error under the carpet, rather I mean sweeping the owner HWND problem under the carpet. I'm sure you wouldn't condone not setting owner HWND correctly.

Comment: @David, of course I wouldn't. But there's no way (prior to D2007) to **set** the HWND for TOpenDialog (or any of the other pre-wrapped standard dialogs).

Comment: @Ken How did people deal with this? Didn't it cause no end of trouble?

Comment: @David: Not once you learned about SetErrorMode. ;) It actually wasn't a big deal, unless you hit one of the circumstances that caused it to happen. It's actually a problem in the VCL's own modal dialogs; that's why D2007+ added TCustomForm's PopupMode and PopupParent properties - to fix Z-order and parentage issues introduced with XP/Vista/Win7. You youngsters missed all the fun. ;)

Comment: @Ken I've been doing it since Delphi 1. Not so young!

Comment: @David: Youngsters. :) I started when Turbo Pascal was a baby, and DOS had a version less than 3.